# How do I stop an Actionlink redirect and instead popup and redirect using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, popup, actionlink

This is script what I have currently -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.RemoveSystem').click(function () {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this system?");
                alert(answer);
                if (answer) 
                    window.location = href;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the link which is there for each record and we can delete each system when we click on its delete button  -

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "RemoveSystem", new { SysNum = item.Id}, new { @class = "RemoveSystem" })%>
```

Now here is the problem the actionlink redirects no matter what happens and I need to stop it. I mean say the user presses cancel on the confirm the actionlink still executes and goes to RemoveSystem Action, where I want it to just stay on the page.I thought of using a HTML hyperlink but I dont know how I should pass id the value to the javascript in that case. Can anyone please help me out ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to prevent the *default* action of the link like this:

```
$('.RemoveSystem').click(function () {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this system?")) 
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
  return false;
});
```

Or this:

```
$('.RemoveSystem').click(function (e) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this system?")) 
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Currently, the link is doing this function but *also* doing what it does with no JavaScript at all, which is to go to the `href` it has...that's the behavior you need to prevent from happening.

Answer (score 2):

Return false if you want to prevent the default action:

```
$('.RemoveSystem').click(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this system?");
    if (answer) 
        window.location = href;
    return false;
});
```

or use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
$('.RemoveSystem').click(function (evt) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this system?");
    if (answer) 
        window.location = href;
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script function add:

```
if (answer)  
    window.location = href;
else
   return false;
```