# Ask for confirmation before user clicks on other links before data submission

Tags: jquery, forms, redirect

I have a form on my html page for updating some custom data. I want to ask a confirmation message to user, if he has updated the data in form and click on some other link on the same html page, before submitting the form.

**How I implemented this:**

I have made boolean variable which keeps the state whether user has updated any field. And I have bind `click` event of all `anchor` tag in the html page using `jquery`. So that when user clicks on any anchor tag on the page, I will check whether state variable is true(value changed) or not. If it is true I want to stop the redirection and ask for confirmation.

I have done till this point. But the problem is I could not stop redirection even if user clicks on `cancel` of confirmation box.

**Here is the code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed = false;
  $("[id^='id_']").live('change', function (){
      GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed = true;
  });
});



$('a').bind('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.customize_option_changed){
        var res = confirm('you have unsaved changes. Do you want to continue?');
        if(res){
            GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.customize_option_changed = false;
            $(this).click();
        }else{
            console.log('stay on same page...');
            // Problem: user redirects to the clicked link even if he reaches here
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any problem in my implementation idea? What is the problem with this code? or Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Invoking click() on the anchor does not make the browser follow the link. Use `window.location.href = $(this).attr('href')`.

Comment: $(this).click() refers to your bound method.
Check this out for an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619214/how-do-i-stop-an-actionlink-redirect-and-instead-popup-and-redirect-using-javasc

Comment: @Flauwekeul: thanks! I shall do that modification. But my problem is I could not stop the redirection if user clicks the cancel button of confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsX7s/2/) works.

```
var GLOBAL_NAMESPACE = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
  GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed = true;
});

$('a').bind('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed){
        var res = confirm('you have unsaved changes. Do you want to continue?');
        if(res){
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        }else{
            console.log('stay on same page...');
        }
    }
});
```

I changed a couple of things:

1. In `$(document).ready()` you're setting `GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed` and in the `bind()` function you're reading `GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.customize_option_changed`
2. Depending on your version of jQuery the `live()` method is replaced by `on()`. I removed this code altogether since for the sake of example I want `GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed` to be true.
3. There's no need to set `GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed` to false if the user confirms leaving the page since he's leaving the page :)
4. And like I said in the comments: I replaced `$(this).click();` by `window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');`

Comment: I agree on your 3rd point. But now if user clicks on any link the confirmation will ask anyway irrespective of whether he changed the form data or not. I think inside the document.ready we should initialize it to false; also updating the `value_changed` variable is also missing. But anyway this will not solve the problem. Because `e.preventDefault()` is not stopping the click event execution.(that's my guess. and pretty sure about that); thanks for answer anyway. :)

Comment: Did you overlook point 2? I removed the whole `live()` block for the sake of example. But [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsX7s/4/) without that code removed. Please note that you might have to swap `live()` for `on()` depending on your version of jQuery. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Okey. I tried with `on` instead of `live`. But still redirection to the clicked link occur irrespective of option selected from confirmation dialog.

Comment: Another [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsX7s/5/), this time with an input. Still works here...Can you add all your relevant HTML? Are you getting errors? What version of jQuery are you using? Also try logging the value of `GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed` in various parts of you code.

Comment: Your answer is correct. In fact some of my a tags works based on ajax. so two click events were generated. The ajax request was getting called anyway. I fixed it. Thanks a ton for your patience. :)